# Python: Manually config Chrome://settings by Selenium remotedriver

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to control chrome://settings via selenium webdriver, the way I'm trying to do it is the following:

```
driver.get('chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com')
a_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//select[contains(@id, "permission")]')))
```

For some reason selenium does not identify the xpath, and in consequence I cannot select it and move inside the settings or change anything

```
*** selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

[image: ch//set]

My selenium version is **selenium==3.141.0**

Answer (score 3):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(
    'chrome://settings/content/siteDetails?site=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com')
temp= driver.execute_script(
    "return document.querySelector('settings-ui').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-main#main').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-basic-page')")
rules = driver.execute_script(
    "return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-privacy-page').shadowRoot.querySelector('settings-animated-pages#pages settings-subpage site-details').shadowRoot.querySelector('div.list-frame:not(div>div.list-frame)')", temp)
location = driver.execute_script(
    "return arguments[0].querySelector('site-details-permission[label=\"Location\"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('#permission')", rules)
camera = driver.execute_script(
    "return arguments[0].querySelector('site-details-permission[label=\"Camera\"]').shadowRoot.querySelector('#permission')", rules)

location.click()
location.find_element_by_id("allow").click()

camera.click()
camera.find_element_by_id("block").click()
```

Its inside shadowRoot so you have to use execute script and go through each shadow root. In above code you just have to change the label in the 'location' line to change other rules as 'rules' object is parent for all other rules.

Comment: Thanks.  Learned something new today

Comment: Still working nowadays. Thanks!